# Multiple IN() operators - No results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
countryName,countrySlug
FROM countries AS Country 
INNER JOIN countries_networks AS n ON Country.id = n.country_id
AND n.network_id IN (1,14)
```

which works fine. However, I now need to add a 'must have' clause to it, so that the n.network_id MUST also be in the set (6,7,8,9). (BTW they can have multiple network_ids, as I'm pulling directly from a lookup table.)

So I tried adding another IN():

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    countryName,countrySlug
    FROM countries AS Country 
    INNER JOIN countries_networks AS n ON Country.id = n.country_id
    AND n.network_id IN (1,14)
AND n.network_id IN (6,7,8,9)
```

which now returns no results at all.

This seems like I'm making a stupid error here. Can anyone see what it is?

Comment: The way you are structuring says that `network_id` must be equal to  (1 or 14) and (6 or 7 or 8 or 9) which is impossible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; you're requiring that `network_id` be present in two non-intersecting lists. It is impossible for a given value `a` to be in both of the following lists:

```
1, 14
6, 7, 8, 9
```

To beat a dead horse, let's look at every value

```
value  list1 list2
------------------
1      x
6            x
7            x
8            x
9            x
14     x
```

That's the entire set of values that falls in either list; anything outside of that scope won't fit *either* condition, and none of the values within the scope fit *both* conditions.

To satisfy your condition where a single `Country` can have multiple `network_id`s based on the `country_network` association table, you can do this:

```
select distinct
    c.countryname, c.countryslug

from country c

join country_network cn1 on cn1.country_id = c.country_id
join country_network cn2 on cn2.country_id = c.country_id

where cn1.network_id in (1, 14) and cn2.network_id in (6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

A given `network_id` **row** cannot simultaneously be in both sets. `(1,14)` and `(6,7,8,9)`

You can achieve your desired result with a self join.

```
... countries_networks cn1 
   join countries_networks cn2 on cn1.country_id = cn2.country_id
where cn1.network_id in (1,14) and cn2.network_id in (6,7,8,9)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on my comment above, try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT countryName,countrySlug
FROM countries AS Country 
WHERE Country.id IN (SELECT n.country_id FROM countries_networks n WHERE n.network_id IN (1,14))
AND Country.id IN (SELECT n.country_id FROM countries_networks n WHERE n.network_id IN (6,7,8,9))
```

Performance wise, there may be a hit from the two sub-queries but it may be inconsequential depending on the number of rows in your tables. I'll have a go at using joins and update...

**UPDATE**

Using a double join, this should yield the results you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT countryName,countrySlug
FROM countries AS Country
INNER JOIN countries_networks n1 ON n1.country_id = Country.id
INNER JOIN countries_networks n2 ON n2.country_id = Country.id
WHERE n1.network_id IN (1,14)
AND n2.network_id IN (6,7,8,9)
```

Answer (score 1):

`IN ()` is a synonym for a series of OR's

So `WHERE a IN (1,2,4)`
can also be written as

```
WHERE (a = 1 OR a = 2 OR a = 4)
```

You are trying to do:

```
WHERE ... a IN (1,14) AND a IN (6,7,8,9)
```

Which can be rewritten as

```
WHERE (a = 1 OR a = 14) AND (n.network_id = 6 OR ....)
```

*Never mind that you're doing it in a join clause and never mind that I did not write out the full equivalent code.* Clearly network_id **cannot** be two different values at the same time, which is why your query never returns anything.